# sqoop job getting failed

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop, sqoop2

Hi I have executed sqoop import from sql server. I am able to unload many a tables but this table is throwing error.

I am using 8 mappers and using CDH 5.2. My 7 mappers are completed successfully but showing below message in the log.

```
Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
  Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
  Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
```

The last mapper runs for some more time and failing . This is the below query getting executed.

```
sqoop import --connect $JDBCconnector --username $UserName --password $sqlServerPassword --hive-table  p2020_sqlserver_lifr.$Hivetable --table 
                $TableName_Schema --hive-import -m 8 -- --schema $SchemaName

SELECT  [SDPMTO], [SDANBY], [SDPMTN], [SDNUMB], [SDAAID], [SDSPATTN], [SDPRAN8], [SDPRCIDLN], [SDCCIDLN], [SDSHCCIDLN], [SDOPPID], [SDOSTP], [SDUKID], [SDCATNM] FROM [proddta].[F4211] WHERE ( [SDDCTO] >= 'P' ) AND ( [SDDCTO] <= 'SZ' )
```

Comment: How is this query different from the others that are working?

Comment: All the tables are different. So the where clause is definitely becoming different. But the sqoop command I have provided is very much same fo each table . 15/01/30 10:46:54 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
Erroe:
15/01/30 10:47:10 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
15/01/30 10:47:17 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 63% reduce 0%
15/01/30 10:47:18 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 75% reduce 0%
15/01/30 10:49:25 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 88% reduce 0%
15/01/30 10:56:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1422480430174_0010_m_000007_0, Status : FAILED
Error: Java heap space

Comment: You need to look a little closer.  There's something different about your non-working query that's causing it to fail when the others succeed.

Comment: Error: Java heap space
15/01/30 11:04:10 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
15/01/30 11:04:10 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1422480430174_0010_m_000007_1, Status : FAILED
Error: Java heap space
Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
15/01/30 11:04:11 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 88% reduce 0%
15/01/30 11:12:14 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1422480430174_0010_m_000007_2, Status : FAILED

job_1422480430174_0010 failed with state FAILED due to:  task_1422480430174_0010_m_000007

Comment: I don't see any useful information in there.  You need to either figure out what is different about the queries that is causing one to fail, or coerce the system into giving you an error message that provides some meaningful information.